# Which is the best analytics service for Android apps?

Tags: android, service, google-analytics, analytics

Which is the best service to monitor my Android app?
I know a lot of services but none of them seems to be better than other.

- Crittercism
- Google Analytics
- Flurry
- Apsalar
- Localytics
- Kontagent
- Countly
- Appsee
- Mixpanel
- Mobclix
- Medialets
- Kissmetrics
- HockeyApp
- [UXCam](https://www.google.jo/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwiltZbDrqjIAhWCCBoKHQ5NC_E&url=https%3A%2F%2Fuxcam.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFtEWCj2KHeT5KlzFDGXjZ144D6LA&sig2=K07wAlcDrOL-7sLUSGwBoQ)

Comment: I think you should use `Google Analytics`

Comment: @MukeshKumar Why do you think that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics is the most intuitive and easy to use web analytics tool on the market today. Its straight-forward user-interface, increases discoverability and accessibility of data - allowing you to quickly get to the information you need to see. Its about "data democratisation", which empowers your team to turn data into actionable information. In fact the user-interface was quite radical when launched in 2007...
Of course, collecting data is the easy step. Planning a data structure that will provide end-users with insight, requires strategic help and experienced hands.

- Motion Charts - animated data in 5 dimensions...!
- Intelligence - automatic and custom alerts
- Custom Reporting - build your own reports
- Mobile reporting - tracks moble visitor and mobile apps usage
- Custom Variables - define and group pages, label visits and
  visitors(Omniture charges  thousands for this!)
- Native 64-bit hardware support
- Much, much faster processing speeds
- Auto-update of Urchin added - for simplified updates
- Configurable Geo DB - improves performance for very large data sets
- Paralell processing (simulataneous processing of profiles)
- Improved export API

All these above features make it more usefull. More details check [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/google-analytics-why-you-probably-dont-need-the-rest/)

Comment: Thanks. I will use Google Analytics